# Saving Julia dataframe to read in R using HDF5

Tags: r, dataframe, julia, hdf5

While reading R datasets in Julia received sufficient attention already, sometimes the results of computations done in Julia need to be readable to R. To accomplish that I was trying to save a [DataFrame.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl) object in HDF5 file. Here is the code so far, written within the restrictions of currently available [HDF5.jl](https://github.com/timholy/HDF5.jl) methods:

```
using DataFrames, HDF5
df = DataFrame(coln1 = 1:4, coln2 = ["M", "F", "F", "M"], coln3 = int8([1, 0, 1, 1]))
h5open("trydf.h5", "w") do file
  g = g_create(file, "df") # create a group
  for cnm in DataFrames._names(df)
    g["$cnm"] = convert(Array, df[cnm])
  end
  attrs(g)["Description"] = "Julia DataFrame columns"
end
```

The dataframe can then be reassembled in R using [rhdf5](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rhdf5.html) package tools.
Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this? Something that does not require to split the dataframe apart and re-assemble in R, losing some column types (e.g. boolean does not work) along the way?

Comment: Are you willing to consider saving to formats other than hdf5?  If the data set is not huge and the Julia data is not already in a data frame, it might make sense to save as, say, a CSV file.

Comment: CSV is indeed a reasonable option with a moderate size dataframe. The appeal of HDF5 however is a possibility of hierarchical structures containing more complex objects than in my minimal example, and it would be helpful to be able to preserve some object structure when exchanging between Julia and R.

Answer (score 3):

The issue of column type limitations was resolved when I was pointed to [RCall.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/RCall.jl) package. This package turns out to be very helpful for integrating Julia and R work. Instead of saving HDF5 in this example, a native RData file can be created:

```
using DataFrames
using RCall

# example DataFrame
df = DataFrame(coln1 = 1:4, coln2 = ["M", "F", "F", "M"], coln3 = [false, true, false, true], coln4 = int8([1, 0, 1, 1]))

# R environment in a session started from Julia
g = globalEnv
reval(rparse("dfls <- NULL"))

# add columns one at a time converting Julia vectors to R-types via   RCall.sexp
#  https://github.com/JuliaStats/RCall.jl/blob/master/src/sexp.jl
for cnm in DataFrames._names(df)
  g[:colcnm] = sexp(convert(Array, df[cnm]))
  reval(rparse("dfls\$$cnm <- colcnm"))
end
reval(rparse("df <- data.frame(dfls)"))
reval(rparse("save(file='dfjulia.RData', df)"))
```